# Katex - how to change superscript size

Tags: math, indices, superscript, katex

I'm using Katex and need to reduce the size of the indices as they are far too big. I've figured out work arounds when the index is a simple number, but as soon as I need to use fractional indices, nothing works. I know I probably need to modify the index size in the javascript library but I don't know how. Does anyone out there know how to do it?